# PATH problem: bash: /usr/local/bin/adb: No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, bash

I've had a working installation of adb and fastboot (for Android debugging and development). It used to be that when I type `adb` it launches the command line help for adb. Now it says this:
`bash: /usr/local/bin/adb: No such file or directory`
as if it's only looking for it in `/usr/local/bin/adb`, right?
Though I still do have it in `/usr/bin/adb` and can still use it by typing the absolute path.

Further more, I have several aliases in my Bash Aliases file; one of which is `sysupgrade` (it does what it sounds like) but when I tried this today, it failed. So I ran the next lines **in terminal** interpreting some help wrong on a forum which says to put it in `/etc/profile`:

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
export PATH
```

But my aliases now work! It's just that adb and fastboot don't. I've tried `which` and `nping` which are all in `/usr/bin` and they all work.

#### Update

Output of `echo $PATH`

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

#### Update 2

`hash -r` didn't show anything. But `hash` showed:

```
hits    command
   1    /usr/local/bin/adb
```

Comment: Give `hash -r` a try.

Answer (score 4):

`adb` was hashed at `/usr/local/bin/adb`, meaning the shell remembered its location and wouldn't look again in the PATH to see that it had been deleted/moved. Normally `hash -r` would unhash everything including `adb`, but it didn't in this case - not sure why, but running `hash -d adb` would also do it. Restarting the shell also unhashes everything.

If you had run `type adb` before fixing the issue, you would have seen this:

```
adb is hashed (/usr/local/bin/adb)
```

This is one of the reasons why `type` is better than `which`.

Answer (score 1):

I still can't pinpoint the root cause of the problem but I fixed it after some trial and error.

I did `which adb` and `which fastboot`

which showed: `/usr/local/bin/adb` and `/usr/local/bin/fastboot`

And I simply did
`sudo rm /usr/local/bin/adb` and `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/fastboot`

exit terminal/restart and I'm good to go.

Now `adb` and `fastboot` correctly execute `/usr/bin/adb` and `/usr/bin/fastboot`

Comment: `which` is useless for debugging this. The `type` builtin would've told you what was really going on.